# How does login get to startx

Tags: login, xorg, tty

Looking at the output of 'ps ax', how does login get to startx?  See below.

init starts /bin/login
login starts startx     -- HOW?  What file is executed to get to startx?

```
1297     1 Ss+  tty1     00:00:00 /bin/login -f
1495  1297 S+   tty1     00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/startx
1519  1495 S+   tty1     00:00:00 xinit /home/./.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/x
1520  1519 Sl   tty1     00:01:38 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg ...
1526  1519 S    tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/xterm ...
1531  1526 S    tty1     00:00:00 twm
```

Tom Dean

Comment: Looing at login.c, after the fork to change to user level priv, login exec's the user shell from etc/passwd.  In my case, this is bash.  At the bottom of my .bash_profile, I have 
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ -n "$XDG_VTNR" ] && [ "$XDG_VTNR" -eq 1 ]; then
  exec startx
fi
This question is answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at login.c, after the fork to change to user level priv, login exec's the user shell from `/etc/passwd`. In my case, this is bash. At the bottom of my `.bash_profile`, I have

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ -n "$XDG_VTNR" ] && [ "$XDG_VTNR" -eq 1 ]; then
exec startx
fi
```

Comment: you mark the question as solved by clicking the green check mark to set it as [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer), not by saying that it's solved